# String Manipulation Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, string, array, ups, nut

I am working on a UPS Monitoring project using NUT Server. My objective is to make a shell script which sends one command and in response receives the status and other parameters from the UPS.

for example

```
#!/bin/bash
status='upsc myups' # command to get the status of UPS
sleep 1
exit 0
```

This is working fine for me but if I declare the 'status' as an array, the response from the ups is stored as a single element

i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a status #declare status as array
# command
status=$(upsc myups)  or status=`upsc myups`
#number of array elements
echo ${status[@]}
exit 0
```

**Number of Elements in status array:**

```
1
```

**Terminal Output/Array Output**

```
echo ${#status[1]}
```

if I echo the array, the output looks like as follows:

```
Init SSL without certificate database
battery.capacity: 9.00 battery.charge: 90 battery.charge.low: 20                                                                 
battery.charge.restart: 0 battery.energysave: no battery.protection: yes  
ups.shutdown: enabled ups.start.auto: yes ups.start.battery: yes   
ups.start.reboot: yes ups.status: OL CHRG ups.test.interval: 604800 
ups.test.result: Done and passed ups.timer.shutdown: -1     
ups.timer.start: -1   
ups.type: offline / line interactive ups.vendorid: 0463
```

As this whole output is saved in a single element of "status" array. I am getting trouble using all the parameter separately for log purposes.

**Desired Output:**

```
battery.capacity: 9.00
battery.charge: 90 
battery.charge.low: 20                                                                 
battery.charge.restart: 0
battery.energysave: no 
battery.protection: yes
```

How can I separate each parameter into an individual element of an array or variable?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: if you browse through the post: in the third section  I have posted the output in response to the command: "Init SSL without certificate database"

Comment: The output of the array and terminal output is similar.

Comment: Currently, the output of the terminal/command response is saved into a single element of the array. And my goal is to separate this string into small chunks to create a saperate array or variables. Which I can use for logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you get back from `upsc` is of the form `keyword: value`, one per line. You can pass this through `sed` to get the form `[keyword]="value"`, and then use this to initialise an associative array:

```
declare -A status="($(upsc myups | sed 's/\(.*\): \(.*\)/ [\1]="\2"/'))"
```

Now you can get the value of any keyword, eg `echo "${status[device.model]}"`.
You can loop through all the keys and values and do what you want:

```
for key in "${!status[@]}"
do    echo "$key: ${status[$key]}"
done
```

---

Note, if you quote your values,

```
status="$(upsc myups)"
echo "${status[@]}"
```

you would have still got a single value, but each value would be on a new line, as in your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider:

```
upsc myups | grep -oP 'battery(\.\w+)+: \S+'
```

Your primary need is to quote your variables:

```
status=$(upsc myups)
echo "$status"
```

Comment: This method is working well to separate each parameter with the help of initial word. But the output is still a single string. I want to separate every element and save it in an array or a variable. Please help

Comment: Then meuh's answer is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use `readarray` bash builtin:

```
readarray status < <(upsc myups)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to assign an array (i.e. enclosed in parentheses) rather than a string to `$status`.

Also set IFS to a newline (`\n`) so that it puts each line (rather than each word) into a separate array element:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' status=( $(upsc myups 2>/dev/null | grep '^battery\.') )

$ printf "%s\n" "${status[@]}"
battery.capacity: 9.00
battery.charge: 90
battery.charge.low: 20
battery.charge.restart: 0
battery.energysave: no
battery.protection: yes

$ declare -p status   # reformatted slightly for readability.
declare -a status='([0]="battery.capacity: 9.00" [1]="battery.charge: 90"
                    [2]="battery.charge.low: 20" [3]="battery.charge.restart: 0"
                    [4]="battery.energysave: no" [5]="battery.protection: yes")'
```

---

PS: If you're going to do significantly more processing with these `upsc` values, I strongly recommend using `perl` or `awk` or `python` instead of `bash` - they're all far better suited to writing complex text-processing tools than `bash` alone.